# HTML Grid Layout

Tags: html, css

I am putting together a grid layout in HTML, this is what I have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/wlindner/HX2eq/.

The attached screenshot is what I am trying to do and I'm really not sure if I'm taking the right approach.  How should I fit the wide box in the bottom right into the correct position?

[image: HTML Grid Layout]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#attendees-box {
    width: 640px;
    height: 200px;
    float:right;
    margin-top:-224px;
}
```

You may need to tweak the numbers.

Comment: That's all I had to do??  Wow...  I really need to take a break.  I can't believe I missed this.  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score -1):

If you need to create or test any HTML grid layout try this site : [HTML web page grid layout generator](http://www.blended-html.com). Click the "Build" button to generate the CSS and HTML code for any layout.